# Hiding Backstage buttons

Tags: ms-word, ribbon

I am trying to hide a small number of backstage buttons/tabs using the CustomUI interface. All my research suggests that the following xml should do it:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >  
  <backstage>   
   <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/> 
   <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false"/>   
   <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>   
  </backstage>
</customUI>
```

but it doesn't. I am trying this with Office 365. Can anyone see anything wrong with the xml or has this functionality been removed from 365?

Answer (score 0):

The answer it seems relates to my .rels file which was referring to the 2006 schema and needed to refer to 2007.